# Should [music] and [song-poetry] be merged?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

Either that, or we should designate [music](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) for questions about music in general (such as when and if it's permissible, for instance) and [song-poetry](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-poetry) for questions about specific songs (such as the source for a song or its lyrics, for instance).

Comment: Perhaps lyrics vs melody?

Answer (score 4):

**If** we split the tags as suggested, then I propose that the *song-poetry* tag be renamed to *songs-poems*.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think they should be merged.

[song-poetry](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-poetry) is largely populated with questions that relate to the words in songs and poetry, which is a significant topic in Judaism in its own right, thanks to the centrality of Tehillim and liturgy. In addition, many of these questions have nothing to do with music, *per se*. This tag also contains some questions about singing, generally, which probably would fit better in [music](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music).

[music](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) is populated with questions relating to music in various ways, including restrictions on making or listening to it, tunes used in songs or non-verbal expressions, and music as intellectual property. Many of these questions have nothing to do with the lyrical content of songs, although some do.

It seems to me that the distinction between these tags, in terms of usage, is already fairly healthy, though a little tightening up  would be good. I recommend the following measures:

- Rename [song-poetry](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-poetry) to `songs-poems`, as [msh210 proposed](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4118/2).
- Improve the writeup for [song-poetry](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-poetry) to make it clear that it's about songs as objects, their lyrical content, and poetry, while questions about music, generally, or the act of singing belong under [music](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music).
- Add `singing` and `tunes` as synonyms for [music](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music).
- Improve the writeup for [music](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) to make it clear that it's about music, generally, including singing, while questions about the lyrical content of songs belong under `songs-poems`.
- Acknowledge that many questions, such as ones about the tunes for individual songs, could well deserve both of these tags, if there's room on their tag lists.
- Sweep through [song-poetry](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-poetry), remove it from questions that not about songs as objects, their lyrical content, or poetry, and add [music](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) to questions where it belongs, including those about song tunes or the act of singing.
- Sweep through [music](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music), remove it from questions that are not about music (though I don't see too many at first glance), add [song-poetry](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-poetry) to questions that it applies to as well, and consider replacing [music](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) with [song-poetry](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-poetry) on questions where there isn't room for both in the tag list, and the latter fits better than the former.